# Changing state of a parent from a child with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a Task component, and each time a task is complete I am trying to update a counter in the parent component, Bot, which holds all of the tasks. However, when I click all of the tasks at the same time, the state (completeTasks) fluctuates instead of strictly increasing.

My Task component, where I call the parent function incrementCompletedTasks (each task takes a different amount of time to complete, which is why I have the setTimeout):

```
const Task = ({ task, eta, onTaskCompletion }) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [isCompleted, setCompleted] = useState(false)
  const seconds = eta / 1000;

  const taskCompletion = () => {
    onTaskCompletion()
    setLoading(false)
    setCompleted(true)
  }

  const handleTaskCompletion = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    setTimeout(taskCompletion, eta)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        isCompleted ? <p className="completedTask">{task} {seconds} {seconds > 1 ? "seconds": "second"}</p> : 
        <p className="task">{task} {seconds} {seconds > 1 ? "seconds": "second"}</p>
      }
      {
        isCompleted ? <img src={checkmark} className="image" alt="checkmark"/> :
        (isLoading ? <img src={loading} className="image" alt="loading" /> : 
        <button onClick={handleTaskCompletion} type="button">Complete Task</button>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

My Bot component, whose completeTasks hook should be incrementing itself each time Task calls it:

```
const Bot = ({ name, type }) => {
  const [completeTasks, setCompleteTasks] = useState(0)

  const incrementCompleteTasks = () => {
    setCompleteTasks(completeTasks+1)
  }

  return (
    <div className="Bot">
      <header>
        <h2 className="botHeader">{name}</h2>
        <h3 className="botHeader">{type}</h3>
        <h4 className="botHeader">Completed Tasks: {completeTasks}</h4>
      </header>
      {
        botData[type].tasks.map(t => <Task task={t.task} eta={t.eta} key={t.eta} onTaskCompletion={incrementCompleteTasks}/>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you share your code in sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-newton-6g9xp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark   It's all in the Bot folder, let me know if it doesn't work, I haven't used this before

Comment: I got it to work with prev => prev + 1. I didn't realize that was a thing. Thank you!

Comment: you want your Completed Tasks incremented value?